# Linux bash script to check internet connection not working

Tags: linux, bash, grep, connection, ping

I want to use a bash script on my raspberry pi to check whether the internet connection is still present.

I found this script which I extended:

```
#!/bin/bash

# I do not work properly
if [[ "$(ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 | grep 'Network is unreachable' )" != "" ]]; then
    echo "Network isn't present"
    sudo shutdown -r 0
    exit 1
fi

# I work properly
if [[ "$(ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 | grep '100% packet loss' )" != "" ]]; then
    echo "Internet isn't present"
    sudo shutdown -r 0
    exit 1
else
    echo "Internet is present"
    exit 0
fi
```

The second part works nice, the first one, however, does not.

I unplugged my Ethernet cable and get an Error message like `connect: Network is unreachable`. So as expected. But I am not understanding why my script is not picking it up? I think it has something to do with it being an error message and not an output. But I do not know how I would have to adjust my script to grep from error messages as well, assuming this is correct.

I found a way how to get the output to be registered by grep by using this line `ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 2> >(grep 'unreachable';)`. However, this still makes my script fail because it is no longer recognized by the rest of that line then. And I also do not entirely understand what `2> >()` does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really need a string comparison here:

`ping` command gives an appropriate return code after it completes execution.

So, you could use something like:

```
 function check_connectivity() {

    local test_ip
    local test_count

    test_ip="8.8.8.8"
    test_count=1

    if ping -c ${test_count} ${test_ip} > /dev/null; then
       echo "Have internet connectivity"
    else
       echo "Do not have connectivity"
    fi
 }

 check_connectivity
```

Comment: Works like a charm and I understand it, nice and simple!

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
x=`ping -c1 google.com 2>&1 | grep failure`
if [ ! "$x" = "" ]; then
echo "Network isn't present"
sudo shutdown -r 0
exit 1
fi
```

**Or for your script I would do:**

```
if [[ "$(ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 | grep '100% packet loss' )" != "" ]]; then
  echo "Internet isn't present"
  sudo shutdown -r 0
  exit 1
elif [[ "$(ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 | grep 'packet loss' | grep -o "1[0-9][0-9]\+%")" != "" ]]; then
  echo "Network isn't present"
  sudo shutdown -r 0
  exit 1
else
  echo "Internet is present"
  exit 0
fi
```

## But i recommending using /sys/class/net instead

```
# Test for network conection
for interface in $(ls /sys/class/net/ | grep -v lo);do
if [[ $(cat /sys/class/net/$interface/carrier) = 1 ]]; then OnLine=1;fi;done
if ! [ $OnLine ]; then echo "Internet isn't present" > /dev/stderr;sudo shutdown -r 0; exit; fi
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need it to be as simple as possible and I do not really understand your recommended way. But I already got it solved :)

Comment: Good that you found a solution..

For sys/class/net:

What:           /sys/class/net/<iface>/carrier
Description:
                Indicates the current physical link state of the interface.
                Posssible values are:
                0: physical link is down
                1: physical link is up

                Note: some special devices, e.g: bonding and team drivers will
                allow this attribute to be written to force a link state for
                operating correctly and designating another fallback interfac

Comment: You can find more info here https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-class-net if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

Returns results without delay:

`$ net lookup example.com`

```
`Didn't find example.com#20`
```

`$ net lookup example.com`

```
`93.184.216.34`
```